# Is not knowing whether X is true inconsistent with assigning a probability to it?

Tags: paradox, probability, bayesian

I have read that it is wise to assign a non zero probability to beliefs, and not 0 or 1. This is because probability represents certainty and you cannot be certain of anything.
xxxxxx
However, if you cannot be certain of anything, then this implies you cannot be certain that the proposition is not apriori true or false. But if a proposition is apriori true or false, its probability is 0 or 1.

For example, for the proposition god exists, if you cannot demonstrate that god is **not** apriori false or true, then how can you be prepared to rule out a 0 or a 1 probability? And if you cannot rule this out, then you cannot say that it is reasonable to assign a (0,1) probability to the proposition that god exists.

As such, is this form of thinking, otherwise known as Cromwell’s rule, misguided?

Comment: Whether the proposition *is* a priori true or false is not relevant to belief probabilities, what is relevant is how much evidence one has to *believe* it true, a priori or not. Your first two paragraphs equivocate on the type of probability in question.

Comment: @Conifold Well the implication is that the belief probabilities are placed in a rational way in so far as they try to reflect the truth. If they weren’t assigned in a rational way, then the whole purpose of Cromwell’s rule falters, since you may as well assign any probability of belief to anything, ignoring all rules. And so if a proposition **cannot** be ruled out as apriori true or false, it stands to reason that one cannot call a 0 or 1 probability irrational.

Comment: What they try is not what they got. "Rational way" for the agents is the way based on the evidence they have, they are not omniscient, so the truth unbeknownst to them is irrelevant. And assigning 0 or 1 based on not being able to rule out something makes no sense regardless. It cannot be ruled out, it cannot be ruled in, if there is one rational thing to do when this is all one got it is not to make the probability 0 or 1.

Comment: @Conifold Yes, that of course makes no sense, which is unsurprising since that is not what was claimed. What was claimed is that you cannot rule out a 0 or 1 probability which follows from not being able to rule out if a proposition is apriori true or false. Thus, if one cannot rule out X, then how can one claim that it is rational to rule out X, which is what you do when assigning a probability between 0 or 1. It seems, rather, that assigning any probability at all seems to assume knowledge that one lacks, as seen here: (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pascal-wager/#Prem2ProbAssiGodsExis)

Comment: When you assign a probability between 0 or 1 to X you do not thereby rule out X, that is not how probability works. And you are trying to assign probabilities to meta-statements about events instead of events themselves, which is not how probability works either. Problems with the probability of God's existence are specific to that, they are not relevant generically. You need to think this through better, it is a mess.

Comment: @Conifold By X I did not mean the proposition, by X I meant the probability of the proposition being 0 or 1. And if you cannot rule out a statement being apriori false or true, then you can’t rule that out. Graham Oppy says the exact same in his Arguing for Gods book, so I must ask if you’re prepared to say his thought on this is a mess. Secondly, nowhere did I state that the problems with the probability of God’s existence are relevant generically. The point is that any probability assignment to God involves knowledge about something that is uncertain, which seems contradictory.

Comment: What does it mean for a "proposition to be a priori true or false" and how does that relate to assiging it a probability of 0 or 1?

Comment: @Dave Presumably, if a proposition can be deemed to be logically necessary or logically inconsistent, then arguably the probability should be either 0 or 1. If one cannot rule out both these possibilities, then it is argued then one cannot rule out those figures.

Comment: i suppose you take some sort of average of your guesses. so you cannot conclusively rule out 1, but then you cannot rule out 0.99... either you get a dstribution of guesses, and you take the middle to assign a probability. ofc this is just common sense, rather than [philosophy](http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~nlf8/teaching/mas2317/notes/chapter2.pdf)

Comment: Well, it would depend, as always, on what we mean. Hence, *ab origine*, define your terms. A hackneyed expression I agree, but it doesn't hurt to remind ourselves of a crucial first step in the *praxis* of philosophy, lest we gobble instead of dine.

Answer (score 1):

As to the question in your title, no, they are not inconsistent. If I keep my eyes closed while I toss a die, then despite not knowing the outcome, I can still assign a probability of 1/6 to the event “When I observe the die, I will discover that it came up 4.”

Answer (score 1):

Some theorists hold that statements about logical truths are exceptions to the application of the Cromwell rule, so they may be considered to have a probability 0 or 1. For myself, I would rather allow that we can be mistaken about logical truths, so even these should not have a probability of 0 or 1. After all, we are none of us logically omniscient.

Probability in the Bayesian framework is concerned with our apprehension of what is true, not with truth itself. Whether something is true, what makes it true, and even whether its truth is a necessary truth, or an *a priori* knowable truth, are separate issues from what evidence we have for its truth.

For example, it is common to think of mathematical theorems as being necessarily true. So, many people would say that the Goldbach conjecture is either true or false, and if it is true, it is a necessary truth. But we have no proof of it, so we are not certain that it is true. Nevertheless there are highly compelling reasons to believe it is true. If you pressed me to put a probability on it, I would say close to 1. The status of the Goldbach conjecture, whether it is necessarily true, or *a priori* knowable, is not excluded by the fact that I cannot presently say that I am certain of it.

Answer (score 0):

> As such, is this form of thinking, otherwise known as Cromwell’s rule, misguided?

In practice, no. One's belief can get arbitrarily close to 0 or 1 which is functionally equivalent to the limit.  In the third paragraph you are engaging in a kind of second order belief modeling, mulling about what values are allowed for the degree of belief in a proposition.  In this kind of formulation, the degree of belief is modeled by a continuous number, thus the difference between (0,1) and [0,1] is a set of measure 0 with respect to the interior of the interval; it's a distinction that does not make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Paul's answer seems to me to be the correct one. Suppose I have tossed a coin and have it in my hand so that I can see it but you cannot. To me, I know for certain that it is heads. You know for certain that from my perspective the probability of it being heads is 1 or 0, but you don't know which. In this scenario, not only is assigning a probability of .5 consistent with not knowing whether the coins is heads, *that is what it means*. When you say you are assigning a probability of 0.5 you are adopting a conventional way of saying that it is heads or it is tails, you don't know which and you have no reason to suspect it is one over the other.